# Python + Gtk + WebKit: scrollbar height not reset after page change

Tags: python, python-3.x, webview, gtk, webkit

The following code **does not reset the vertical scrollbar** after a page changed **to a smaller height**.

It's **reproducible**:

1. **Execute the script**
   1.1 Google.com loads in fullscreen
   1.2 Vertical scrollbar: **initial height**
2. **Search for something**
   2.1 The page will change
   2.2 the vertical scrollbar **increases**
3. **Click the Google Logo** *(upper left)*
   3.1 The page will change back to Google.com 
   3.2 The vertical scrollbar **keeps the height** of step 2 **instead of being reset** to step 1

I guess there must be a setting that I'm missing.

Any idea? Thank you!

```
import gi

gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('WebKit', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, WebKit, GLib, Gdk

if __name__ == '__main__':
    URL = 'http://google.com'

    browser = WebKit.WebView()
    browser.load_uri(URL)

    win = Gtk.Window()
    swin = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
    swin.add_with_viewport(browser)
    swin.set_hexpand(True)
    swin.set_vexpand(True)
    swin.set_policy(Gtk.PolicyType.AUTOMATIC, Gtk.PolicyType.AUTOMATIC)
    win.add(swin)
    win.fullscreen()
    win.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```

Comment: @stovfl `add_with_viewport()` exists, at least in the `pygtk` docs. I probably mixed up the docs (facepalm). It works. If you add it as an answer, I'll accept. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question**: WebKit: scrollbar height not reset after page change

Using

```
swin.add_with_viewport(browser)
```

This will be very wrong for most widgets that support native scrolling, use instead

```
swin.add(browser)
```

---

#### From the Documentation: Gtk 3.0 » Classes

> [Gtk.ScrolledWindow.add_with_viewport(child)](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/ScrolledWindow.html#Gtk.ScrolledWindow.add_with_viewport)
>
> Deprecated since version 3.8: `Gtk.Container.add()` will automatically add a `Gtk.Viewport` if the child doesn’t implement `Gtk.Scrollable`.